Normalising a nested JSON
I'm struggling to normalise nested attributes in a JSON using python data frames.
My JSON structure is:
{
   "aaData": [
     {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "NestedAttribute1": [
         {
          "id": "123",
          "value": "abc"
         }
       ],
        "NestedAttribute2": [
         {
          "id": "456",
          "value": "def"
         }
       ],
        "NestedAttribute3": [
         {
          "id": "789",
          "value": "ghi"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
        "Name": "DEF",
        "NestedAttribute1": [
         {
          "id": "987",
          "value": "xyz"
         }
       ],
        "NestedAttribute2": [
         {
          "id": "654",
          "value": "uvw"
         }
       ],
        "NestedAttribute3": [
         {
          "id": "321",
          "value": "rst"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}

In reality, there are many nested attributes and I have a separate table with the list of them.
I'm reading in the JSON and converting to dataframe with the following:
after reading in the JSON and converting to a dataframe, I am extracting the records with:
df = pf.json_normlize(df['aaData'])

This gives me two columns, 'Name' and 'NestedAttribute'.  I'd like to now split the 'NestedAttribute' into the 2 columns (NestedAttribute_id and NestedAttribute_Value).
I've tried using normalise a second time, but it's not working as I think it thinks it's a nested array due to be enclosed by the []
I know I'm missing something obvious, so hoping someone can put me out of my misery and  give me a point.
The output I want to get to is:



Name
NestedAttribute1_id
NestedAttribute1_value
NestedAttribute2_id
NestedAttribute2_value
NestedAttribute3_id
NestedAttribute3_value




ABC
123
abc
456
def
789
ghi


DEF
987
xyz
654
uvw
321
rst



Thanks for any help.

Your update to the question changes the answer.  You would be better off extracting the data first, then pushing it into a data frame.
rows = []
for elem in data['aaData']:
    row = {}
    for k, v_list in elem.items():
        if k == 'Name':
             row[k] = v_list
             continue
        val_dict = v_list[0]
        for k2, v in val_dict.items():
            row[f'{k}_{k2}'] = v
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df 
# returns:
  Name NestedAttribute1_id NestedAttribute1_value NestedAttribute2_id NestedAttribute2_value NestedAttribute3_id NestedAttribute3_value
0  ABC                 123                    abc                 456                    def                 789                    ghi
1  DEF                 987                    xyz                 654                    uvw                 321                    rst


If you look at the documentation for json_normalize, there are examples of how to do exactly what you want. The records you want are in the NestedAttribute key; additional metadata for each record is the Name key.
import pandas as pd

data = {
   "aaData": [
     {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "NestedAttribute": [
         {
          "id": "123",
          "value": "abc2"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
        "Name": "DEF",
        "NestedAttribute": [
         {
          "id": "456",
          "value": "def2"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}

pd.json_normalize(data['aaData'], 'NestedAttribute',
    'Name', record_prefix='NestedAttribute_')

This returns:
  NestedAttribute_id NestedAttribute_value Name
0                123                  abc2  ABC
1                456                  def2  DEF


Thanks, I've got that to work now which is great.  The challenge I have is that I have a list of nested attributes. I've read the pandas docs and it suggests I can pass a list which I've tried but it fails.  I'd changed 'NestedAttribute' to a list of names.  Is it possible to pass a list?  If not I think I can put in a loop to get around it.  Thanks.

i would need an example of what you are looking for.

Hi, I've updated the post to expand the json and expected results where there are multi nested attributes

updated for changed to the question.

You could convert the input JSON to a dictionary and then use a list comprehension to create a modified dictionary that is input to pandasDataFrame.from_dict:
import pandas as pd
import json

s = """{
   "aaData": [
     {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "NestedAttribute": [
         {
          "id": "123",
          "value": "abc2"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
        "Name": "DEF",
        "NestedAttribute": [
         {
          "id": "456",
          "value": "def2"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}"""

aaData = json.loads(s)['aaData']

d = [
    {
        'Name': d1['Name'],
        'NestedAttribute_id': d2['id'],
        'NestedAttribute_value': d2['value']
    }
    for d1 in aaData
    for d2 in d1['NestedAttribute']
]

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d))

Prints:
  Name NestedAttribute_id NestedAttribute_value
0  ABC                123                  abc2
1  DEF                456                  def2

